# Representing set of functions from finite set to finite set

Tags: python

I'm wondering is there a good way to create a set of functions from a finite set A to the set of number from 1 to n in python?

For example, if `A={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}` and `n=2`, then the set of functions can be thought of as all possible subsets of A. But how would you implement it in python?

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? Maybe I just don't have enough background in set theory, but I don't understand what you mean. Are you looking for every subset of `A` of **length** 1 to n?

Comment: No. Given two sets A and B, he's looking for every function from A to B

Comment: What is your definition of function: each element has exactly one image, or each element has exactly one image?

Comment: @Riccardo Ohh, it's a different meaning of "function". I was thinking a `def`. This is over my head.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes he does want to generate a function with def, but wants to generate all the possible functions given inputs and outputs

Answer (score 4):

here is a generator of all the functions from set A to set B:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import product

def f_generator(A, B):
    def f_template(d, x):
        return d[x]
    for b_values in product(B, repeat=len(A)):
        yield partial(f_template, dict(zip(A, b_values)))
```

For example, you can use it in the following way:

```
A = ["a", "b"]
B = [1, 2, 3]
for f in f_generator(A, B):
    # f is the function, and you can use it as you expect: y=f(x)
    print(f'f("a")={f("a")}, f("b")={f("b")}')
```

Which prints the following output (one line for every function):

```
f("a")=1, f("b")=1
f("a")=1, f("b")=2
f("a")=1, f("b")=3
f("a")=2, f("b")=1
f("a")=2, f("b")=2
f("a")=2, f("b")=3
f("a")=3, f("b")=1
f("a")=3, f("b")=2
f("a")=3, f("b")=3
```

You can also have a list (or a set) of all the possible functions (be careful: there could be many!!):

```
functions = list(f_generator(A, B))
f = functions[3] # the 4th function
```

You can now use `f` as a normal function (for example you can do `f("b")`)